# ALL MY PICTURES DELETED UPON SWITCHING FROM WINDOWS TO UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu

All my pictures and important info got deleted, alon with my exodus wallet recovery phrase and everything!! Is there a way i could get those data back??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't explicitly wipe out the drives, you can still get your stuff. The OS just lost track of where everything is.
If you load a Windows image to a stick and boot from it, you will probably find your files.
Althoght they wont be inside the Documents folder or whatever default folders windows comes with. You will have to get into your drive and search for the folder. The path will probably under users or something.

Comment: I had C drive, E drive and D drive. E and D had the pictures, when installing ubuntu i only formatted C drive and put the E and D on "do not use this partition" then when i installed ubuntu, i mounted E and D, went into them and there are no pictures, if i go back to windows will i get my data back?

Comment: Dont install windows again, just boot your computer from a USB with a windows image and search those drives. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, i reformated the drives when i installed ubuntu, could that be the case?

Comment: Yeah, if you did that then there is no going back. If you are REALLY desperate you can keep then drives intact (don't add anything) and look for someone who can make the drive readable. This can happen because the files are not deleted, just marked as such so the OS can write over those directories.

Comment: On a side note, maybe you can try this: https://www.stellarinfo.com/support/kb/index.php/article/can-the-formatted-data-be-recovered-after-formatted-the